# VS2017 Build failing because of react/types/index.d.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I have set up a Typescript + React project in VS2017. I am using webpack to compile the tsx, which is compiling fine.

But now when i build the project, it's failing due to some random sytax errors in `node_modules\@types\react\index.d.ts` (i have installed all the latest versions of typescript, react).

> Error     Build:'>' expected.

What are my options for getting round this, how can I get it to build properly, or just ignore this error and continue?

tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "include": [
    "./PageModels/src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of Visual Studio fixed this for me, the build was using a different version of TypeScript to the one i had installed via npm.